# Is there a library to make iOS/Android play nice with jQuery that's not jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, android, ios

I'm looking for a library, or a collection of plugins, to make touch devices play nice with jQuery. Specifically for touch events like scrolling divs and anchored border layouts.

Comment: Voting to close under official reason: "Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution(s) Found:

http://cubiq.org/iscroll

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/iscroll-wrapper

http://neave.github.com/touch-scroll/

Answer (score -2):

If you use lighttpd (cydia) you can load jQuery standard, I use it in my web based app and have nothing to complain (scrolling divs I can't tell you, my app doesn't need them).

Comment: Not at all what I'm asking, but I appreciate the time you took to reply.

Comment: ok... you asked Not jquery Mobile, I say Jquery standart is fine -:)